# Handle both AJAX and requestAction calls from one controller action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

My question is simple.

I'd research this in the CakePHP manual but GoDaddy is down today and so is http://www.cakephp.org

Inside a controller's action (Cake 1.3) is it possible to check if the call is made with requestAction. I want to perform the same task but handle both AJAX and requestAction from the same action.

Also, can you explain the difference between how this would be done in Cake 1.3 and Cake 2.0 as I'm upgrading shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if request is AJAX:

**CakePHP 1.3**

```
$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()
```

**CakePHP 2.x**

```
$this->request->is('ajax')
```

**Edit**

Detect if the action was called by `requestAction()`, tested on CakePHP 2.x.

```
$this->request->params['requested']
// set to (int) 1 if called by requestAction 
// won't be set if it was not called by requestAction
```

Not sure about 1.3. Call `debug($this)`, as suggested by Davor Lozic, or `pr($this)` with `debug` set to 1 or greater on `core.php`, and check if it is present.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to check if it's a requestAction or just should I just assume it is if it's not ajax.

Comment: I think you have some property or something like that isRequested. :D Try with debug($this) and find something like that. :)

Comment: Edited the answer to cover the `requestAction` test.